# Wrong line numbers in component stack trace [TS + React]

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, ts-loader

**Problem**

I'm adding an error boundary to my client-side React app. In development, I want to display the error with a stack trace in the browser window, similar to create-react-app's or nextjs's error overlays. Using webpack's `devtool` option, I'm able to generate a stack trace with the correct filename, but the wrong line number.

```
// This is what renders in the browser window
Error: You got an error!
    at ProjectPage (webpack-internal:///./src/pages/ProjectPage.tsx:96:11) // <-- 96 is the wrong line

// This is what shows up in the console
Uncaught Error: You got an error!
    at ProjectPage (ProjectPage.tsx?8371:128) // <-- 128 is the correct line
```

**What I've tried**

- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42747034/webpack-babel-wrong-line-numbers-in-stack-trace) suggests different `devtool` settings, but none of the ones I've tried provide correct line numbers.
- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37174721/webpack-dev-server-how-to-get-error-line-numbers-of-orignal-files) suggests changing the `retainLines` babel setting in
  webpack, but I'm not using babel to transpile my code, I'm using
  ts-loader. Also, the babel docs [suggest this option is a workaround](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/options#retainlines) for people not using source maps, which shouldn't be an issue here.
- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50223991/how-to-make-react-create-app-production-error-boundary-map-to-source-code) suggests an external library to parse the stack trace. I tried it, but it simply parses the existing trace into objects and the line numbers are still wrong.
- The [React docs](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/07/26/error-handling-in-react-16.html#component-stack-traces) suggest using [`babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx-source`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx-source) but again, I'm not using babel to transpile my code. Should I be?

I'm not sure if this is a problem with ts-loader, webpack, or some other fundamental step I'm not understanding about source mapping. Setting a debugger in `componentDidCatch` and inspecting the error gives me the wrong line number, but when it gets logged to the console it's correct. It seems that the console has an additional step to map the correct line numbers; is this something I need to do manually?

**ErrorBoundary.tsx**

```
class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component {
  state = {
    error: null,
  };

  static getDerivedStateFromError(error) {
    return {
      error,
    };
  }

  componentDidCatch(error, errorInfo) {
    // Line numbers are wrong when inspecting in the function, but correct when logged to the console.
    console.log(error, errorInfo);
  }

  render() {
    return this.state.error ?
      <ErrorPage error={this.state.error} /> :
      this.props.children;
  }
}
```

**ErrorPage.tsx**

```
const ErrorPage = ({ error }) => {
  if (__DEV__) {    
    return (
      <Layout title={error.name}>
        <h1>{error.name}: {error.message}</h1>
        <pre>{error.stack}</pre>
      </Layout>
    );
  }

  // Display a nicer page in production.
};
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "lib": ["es2015", "dom"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es6"
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = (env, argv) => {    
  return {
    mode: isProduction ? 'production' : 'development',
    output: {
      path: path.join(__dirname, env.output_path),
      filename: 'app.bundle.js',
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.jsx'],
    },
    devtool: isProduction ? 'source-map' : 'eval-source-map',
    entry: ['./src/index.tsx'],
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.ts(x?)$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          loader: 'ts-loader',
        },
        ...
      ],
    },
    devServer: {
      contentBase: path.join(__dirname, env.output_path),
      disableHostCheck: true,
      historyApiFallback: true,
      headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*',
      },
    },
  };
};
```

Comment: experiment w/ changing source map type in webpack config

Comment: @frozen: Thanks, I've done that. I didn't exhaustively try every single one, but I did try all the ones that I had seen suggested. Is there one in particular you'd recommend?

Comment: Any luck here? Having the same issue

Comment: @tmm1: Didn't get it to work. I ended up using the error overlay plugin for webpack: http://npm.im/error-overlay-webpack-plugin

Answer (score 4):

I ended up using [error-overlay-webpack-plugin](http://npm.im/error-overlay-webpack-plugin) to solve my problem. While it didn't solve the low-level issue in my question (why aren't the line numbers correct in the stack trace?), it did solve my meta-issue (display a nice stack trace in dev) in a much simpler way. Maybe others will find this solution useful as well:

```js
// webpack.config.js

const ErrorOverlayPlugin = require('error-overlay-webpack-plugin');

const plugins = [
  ...
];

if (!isProduction) {
  plugins.push(new ErrorOverlayPlugin());
}

return {
  ...
  plugins,
};
```